# Notation for time to events

Tags: functions, notation

What are the appropriate notations for time to events ?

For example if $t_1 < t_2 <.....<t_k$ are event times and $n_1 < n_2 <.....<n_k$ are the corresponding counts of events.

Is the following appropriate ?

**Time to first event**

$$T_{0} = \min \left\{ n_i \neq  0\right\}$$

**Time to last event**

$$T_{f} = \max \left\{ n_i \neq  0\right\}$$

**Time to peak event count**

$$T_{f} = \left\{ n_i = n_{max}\right\}$$

$n_{max}$ is the peak even count.

Comment: No. You are not telling us what you're taking the minimum of. Good notation includes both the condition you are quantifying over ($n_i\neq0$) and the quantity that is being selected $(t_i)$

Comment: @FShrike Ok. How to show both condition and quantity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise: $$\begin{align}T_0:&=\min_{n_i\neq0}t_i=\min\{t_i:n_i\neq0\}\\T_f:&=\max_{n_i\neq0}t_i=\max\{t_i:n_i\neq0\}\\T_{\text{peak}}&:=t_i,\,n_i=n_{\text{max}}\end{align}$$Your original expressions only suggested a minimum / maximum over the $n$ rather than the times you want, the $t$.